# Call react js function from html file

Tags: html, reactjs

I am developing a web app where I need to do certain things in React JS.
I will get certain data in script tag added in html file.
I need to call a react js function from script tag in html.
How can i do this.

```html
<html>
  <script>
    callReactFunction();
  </script>
</html>
```

In React JS,

```html
class Example {
    function callReactFunction() {
       alert('sample');
    }
}
```

But this is not working.
How to call function in react js from html file.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a class and a function inside that class. you have to first create an instance of that class and call the function on it.

```js
var obj = new Example();
obj.callReactFunction();
```

And i can't see any ReactJS related thing in your code. this is just HTML and Javascript

Comment: Thanks for your answer. On trying this I am getting Example as undefined in html file.

Comment: I need to do exactly like this.
https://gist.github.com/primaryobjects/64734b8fe3f54aa637f444c95f061eed
but with out importing react.js and react.dom.js as i am injecting it via nodemodules.

Comment: `ReactDOM.render` returns a reference to the created component. so you can use that to call a function inside the component.

Comment: I am getting ReactDom as undefined in index.html file.

Comment: You have to load ReactJS script to your HTML ReactDom to work